# Waterline ORM inserting blank cells on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I've a Sails app, that uses MySQL as the DB (well, MySQL and others, but the problem is with MySQL). My problem is that is creating a record on the DB table, but all the cells are empty, and I don't understand why! Let me share the code and the table definition:

```
 CREATE TABLE `components` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `column1` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 `column2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `group` INT,
 `subgroup` INT,
 `column3` INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`column1`) REFERENCES `table1`(`recipe_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`group`) REFERENCES `table_groups`(`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`subgroup`) REFERENCES `table_groups`(`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`column3`) REFERENCES `table2`(`id`))  
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sails model definition:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysqlDb',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  column1: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },
  column2: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },      
  group: {
    type: 'integer',
    required: true
  },
  subgroup: {
    type: 'integer',
    required: true
  },
  column3: {
    type: 'integer'
  }
};
```

Waterline create query:

```
const data = {
  column1: '383qa8475dd11231aa682y2728172y12',
  column2: 'canvas',
  groups: 2,
  subgroup: 5,
  column3: 1
};

Components.create(data).exec((error, results) => {
  if(error) console.error(error);
  else console.log('Created!');
});
```

It doesn't break, but the record on MySQL is empty, so why is inserting everything empty??? In the INT columns, is inserting a 0.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... I found the problem. I forgot to wrap the column names, in the model, inside attributes key, so the model should be like this:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysqlDb',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    column1: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    column2: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },      
    group: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    },
    subgroup: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    },
    column3: {
      type: 'integer'
    }
    }  
};
```

Very silly mistake, but it cost me HOURS! Anyway, it is silly, but I will leave my question here, if anyone makes the same mistake.